# "stream ended unexpectedly" on clone

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I try to clone but I get a rollback. I could clone at another computer previously but now I get a rollback and I don't know why:

```
C:\Users\Niklas\montao>hg clone https://niklasr@bitbucket.org/niklasr/montao
http authorization required
realm: Bitbucket.org HTTP
user: niklasr
password:
destination directory: montao
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: connection ended unexpectedly

C:\Users\Niklas\montao>
```

Currently I'm just trying to do it over again but I suspect that it wil ltime out, can you tell me how to debug more what's happening and possibly resolve the issue? I ran it in debug mode and this is what happens.

```
adding google_appengine/lib/django_1_3/django/contrib/localflavor/locale/mn/LC_M
ESSAGES/django.mo revisions
files: 10223/50722 chunks (20.15%)
transaction abort!
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Your TCP connection to bitbucket is dying before the whole repo is downloaded -- probably a flaky net connection or a full disk.  If it's the former you can do it in small chunks using `-r` like this:

```
hg init montao
cd montao
hg pull -r 50 https://niklasr@bitbucket.org/niklasr/montao  # get the first 50 changesets
hg pull -r 100 https://niklasr@bitbucket.org/niklasr/montao  # get the next 50 changesets
...
```

That should only be necessary if something's wrong with your network route to bitbucket or the repository is incredibly huge.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The repo is about 250 MB large but I'm trimming it down to a more appropriate size and I'm thinking of creating a new repository with just what is needed (since this repo was used for many years and accumulated some dirt e.g. binaries and libraries that could be excluded). I'm going to try and pull it in chunks and if that doesn't work I'm going to create a new repo with just what I need and not the rather large change history. I can work with this repository from my other computer but that is a much newer computer.

Comment: 250MB isn't big.  Something's wrong w/ your network not your computer.

Comment: For me also same issue.All developers except one cannot clone the source code.I tried the above,but was unable to get the entire code.

Comment: This does seem the case, yet the root cause appears to be different. The fact is, `hg` tries to load the entire stream into memory - which can be impossible for especially large repos, or if the client is constrained in memory (e.g. for `cpython`'s, some are a few _gigabytes_ in size).

Comment: You only need to add `cd montao` before pulling

Comment: Just only `hg update` after each step or `-u` attribute.

Comment: Works great for me!

Answer (score 16):

An easier syntax compared to `Ry4an Brase`'s answer:

```
hg clone -r 1 https://niklasr@bitbucket.org/niklasr/montao  # get the first 1 changeset
cd montao
hg pull -r 50    # first 50 changesets
hg pull -r 100   # first 100 changesets
...
hg pull          # all remaining changesets
hg update        # create working copy
```

Comment: since you propably won’t want to add all that by hand you can use simple scripting: `hg clone -r 1 https://niklasr@bitbucket.org/niklasr/montao; cd montao; for i in {1..100}; do hg pull -r ${i}00; done; hg update`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using TortoiseHg Workbench, I found checking "Use compressed transfer" under Options in the Clone dialog worked for me.

Comment: Should that read "Use uncompressed transfer"? That's the closest option in 4.4.2, and checking that option worked for me with a ~500MB repo that kept failing over ssh.